# How to do a custom EJB/JPA mapping type?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I want to store a property into the database as a Long, but use the object with helper methods in the code.

However the object type is a custom type I have that has an internal value (a long) that I want to store to the database.

```
public final class MyBean extends Number implements Serializable, Comparable<MyBean>
{
    private long myValue;

    public MyBean(Long value) { this.myValue = value; }

    // Other helper methods and overrides

    public MyBean valueOf(Long data)
    {
        return new MyBean(data);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return String.valueOf(myValue);
    }
}
```

This is how I am using it:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mybeans")
public class MyBean implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    MyBean myBean;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "mybean", nullable = false)
    public MyBean getMyBean() { return myBean; }
    public void setMyBean(MyBean value) { this.myBean = value; }
}
```

Deserializing this object calls toString and works fine (jax-rs/jersey). But when I try to pull it out of the database using my EJB, the error I get is:

> The object [1,427,148,028,955], of class [class java.lang.Long], could
>   not be converted to [class com.MyBean]

Saving it produced the error

> Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of com.MyBean. Use
>   setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.

Which makes sense.

But what methods can I add in to male the EJB get the long as the value and use the long to set up a new object?

**ANSWER:**

Making the class @Embeddable and adding the following attributes worked.

```
@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name="value", column=@Column(name="mybean"))
})
```

(I didn't add EmbeddedId because I added a serial primary key id and just made this a column)

The one caveat is that it won't work with dynamic weaving. I had to add

```
<property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static"/>
```

to my persistence.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try making `MyBean` an [Embeddable](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Embeddable.html) to use that as an [EmbeddedId](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EmbeddedId.html), something like this:

```
@Embeddable
public final class MyBean extends Number implements Serializable, Comparable<MyBean> {

    private Long myValue;

    public MyBean(Long myValue) {
        this.myValue = myValue;
    }

    // Other helper methods and overrides

    public MyBean valueOf(Long data) {
        return new MyBean(data);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(myValue);
    }

}
```

In your entity, `MyBean` will be an [EmbeddedId](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EmbeddedId.html) and will look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mybeans")
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private MyBean myBean;

    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverride(name="myValue", @Column(name="mybean_id"))
    public MyBean getMyBean() {
        return myBean;
    }

    public void setMyBean(MyBean myBean) {
        this.myBean = myBean;
    }

}
```

Adjust `MyBean` as you need, such as making `Transient` some attributes.

Comment: Awesome! Works perfect. Thanks. The one caveat is that I had to turn on Static weaving for EclipseLink. It didn't like dynamic weaving.